# Convert Object to Array Over Socket in client

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am building a Android Client for a game which is connected in a Java server. I have this code in the server

```
for (int i = 0; i < diceRolled.length; i++) {
            diceRolled[i] = (int) ( 1 + Math.random() * 6);
}
List<int[]> dice = Arrays.asList(diceRolled);
output.writeObject(dice);
```

which create an Object and it is passing it over a socket to the client.
But in the client I need to convert it to back to an array. I tried

```
try {
        ObjectInputStream what = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        int[] myDice = (int[]) what.readObject();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it didn't work. Where are my mistakes?

*Edit:*
**LOGCAT Log**

```
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:81)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:169)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2098)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.pickominoclient.GameActivity$1.onClick(GameActivity.java:65)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-19 15:15:18.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can we see error log or what made it "not work"? At first glance you're sending a java.util.List over the socket and trying to read the object as an int[], which will not work as they are different objects

Comment: @RyanS logcat posted.

Also I am afraid that you are right about int[] that I am trying to read but I need to convert the object into an array. Is there another way to send / receive it without all these converts? Array => List => Object? I have to do the same, reversed, into the client?

Comment: You should be able to send the array directly. Arrays are objects in java, and as long as the underlying type (int in this case) can be serialized you can send an Array using the ObjectOutputStream. You should not have to do any wrapping or converting

Comment: @RyanS yeah I am using ObjectOutputStream, it's the output, that you can see in my code but I didn't know that I can send it w/o converting. Thanks. I am trying this right now.

Comment: Have you even googled the exception? It clearly states: Thrown when you attempt a network operation on the main thread. You should be using AsyncTasks. That is in addition to the answer already posted.

Answer (score 2):

Server sending
`List<int[]> dice = Arrays.asList(diceRolled);`

Application trying to "rebuild" `int[] myDice = (int[]) what.readObject();`

You should be casting to list not to array